# Appending text to div using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a div and i want to use JS to append text to the div. Currently in my code , the text appears but not on the div.

Why is it not appending onto the div `panel` ?

```js
$('.panel').append(
  '<div class="container" style=" width:30%"> ' +
  '<p class="name"> item.name</p>' +
  '</div>'
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="panel" id="panel">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works for me, I don't see any issue here.

Comment: *the text appears but not on the div.* How do you know, give some border to your div to check if this really doesn't work.

Comment: `item.name` shouldn't be part of string.

Comment: yeah works for me too. inspect element you will find your code working fine

Comment: @Derek Brown, it does work after your edit :D

Comment: @wscourge I didn't change anything.  I think the code works all along =D

Comment: @wscourge there was never an issue

Comment: I guess an issue was placement of javascript in the document.

Comment: @Mr.Alien, your text appears on the div? The item names doesn't show on my panel but it shows outside the panel

Comment: @pogba CSS issue probably

Comment: @Mr.Alien I guess OP is trying to add property value but not using correct syntax.

Comment: @MohammadUsman that's a different issue altogether that he is trying to add a dynamic value in the string.. not sure.. too confusing

Comment: Maybe i am quite sure i am not really understanding what append means. I am expecting the name of my items to appear on the panel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why is it not appending onto the div panel ?

**It works as expected**, just add some `border-color` to the `container` *div* to verify.

```js
$('.panel').append(
  '<div class="container" style=" width:30%"> ' +
  '<p class="name"> item.name</p>' +
  '</div>'

);
```

```css
.container
{
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="panel" id="panel"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.panel').append(
  '<div class="container" style=" width:30%"> ' +
  '<p class="name">'+item.name+'</p>' +
  '</div>'
);
```

Comment: this is just a copy and paste of my question :)

Comment: No.. if item is an object then you have to concat like this way.

Comment: you should provide some kind of explanation with your answer

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
('#panel').append(
        '<div class="container" style=" width:30%"> '+
        '<p class="name">' + item.name+'</p>'+
         '</div>'

    );
```

Comment: Also make sure this script code is in $('document').ready(function{...});